# How can I update my API to use the async keyword without using await for all callers

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, async-await

I am trying to port some `TcpClient` dependant code to .net 4.5, using `StreamSocket` and `DataReader` instead.

I have a function named `ReadLine()` which is used everywhere. By using `DataReader` in the body (`LoadAsync()`) of this code, my method is forced to be marked with the `async` keyword.

The chain reaction is as follows:
Now I have hundreds of places where I have to add `async` to calling methods and apply await to underlying `async` method calls.

This leads me to my next question...
Is there an easy way to wrap `ReadLine()` so that calling methods are not aware that it's an asynchronous method, so that I don't have to change the rest of my code?

Also...
I often use this method call in a loop, from multiple places. If these methods are now marked `async`, i'm afraid I might be reading data off a stream when I shouldn't be, which will cause all sorts of nightmares. Is it a problem or am I thinking too far ahead?

Comment: Do you really need to make ReadLine async?

Comment: I don't want it to be async, but because I am using await in this method - the compiler is forcing me to mark it with async - which starts off the chain reaction.

Comment: Marking it async doesn't mean you have to await it whenever you call it. You are marking it async because you have used await inside the method.

Comment: I should have mentioned that ReadLine() is a function which returns a Task<string>.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c Ok, but does it implement all other requirements for being awaitable? i.e. GetAwaiter/BeginAwait/EndAwait? if it does then you have to modify your code as you've described :)

Comment: [You should be careful when doing this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Also... I often use this method call in a loop, from multiple places. If these methods are now marked async, i'm afraid I might be reading data off a stream when I shouldn't be, which will cause all sorts of nightmares. Is it a problem or am I thinking too far ahead?

If you always use `await` whenver you call `*Async` methods, then your `async` methods will act just like synchronous methods (except they won't block). So using `await` in a loop will work just like you expect.

---

`async` does indeed "grow" through the code base. I usually think of this as similar to the old story about "turtles all the way down"; others have called it a "zombie virus".

I describe [the deadlock situation](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in detail on my blog. As I state there, the best option is to allow `async` to grow.

If you *must* create a [synchronous wrapper for an asynchronous method, see Stephen Toub's advice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). You can use `Task.Result`, but you need to do two things:

- Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere. This will sidestep the deadlock situation.
- Be aware that `Result` has different error handling semantics.

For your particular example, something like this should suffice:

```
private async Task<string> ReadLineAsync()
{
  ... // *Every* await in this method and every method it calls
      // must make use of ConfigureAwait(false).
}

public string ReadLine()
{
  try
  {
    return ReadLineAsync().Result;
  }
  catch (AggregateException ex)
  {
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
    throw;
  }
}
```

Please carefully consider the complexity before choosing a mixed synchronous/asynchronous code base. It's not as easy as it first appears.

P.S. Generally speaking, TCP/IP code should all be asynchronous anyway. It's usually a good idea to have a continuous asynchronous read going on a socket.

Comment: Excellent answer! Excellent blog post!

Answer (score 2):

Make a ReadLineAsync function and a ReadLine function.
In the ReadLine function you can call ReadLineAsync like this:

```
var readLineTask = ReadLineAsync(); 
readLineTask.Wait()
```

Comment: This will make the compiler happy but it will not wait for ReadLine to be complete. You now have a race condition.

Comment: +1. Note though that this leads to a deterministic deadlock in at least WinForms and ASP.NET.

Comment: Your suggestion makes perfect sense. In the ReadLine method, instead of awaiting ReadLineAsyn, I call Result on it.

Comment: Perfect. Call the Result on task, after it completes.

Answer (score 0):

Marking it async doesn't mean you have to await it whenever you call it. You are marking it async because you have used await inside the method.

Which means you don't have to mark other methods as async just because you call `ReadLine()` there.

For your readline method to be awaitable it has to return a `Task` or `Task<T>`.