# c# .net 4.5 async await Task.Wait() blocking issue

Tags: c#, .net, deadlock, .net-4.5, async-await

I have the following extension method:

```
internal static string ReadLine(this DataReader stream)
{
   Task<string> line = ReadLineAsync(stream);
   // line.Wait(); - Not Required, as next call blocks
   return line.Result;
}
```

It's basically a Synchronous method call wrapper for an Asynchronous method call that returns a string. The code works fine if I step through it line by line, however it seems that if I let it execute freely, I encounter an indefinite block. Any ideas?

Related to a previous question I posted: [How can I update my API to use the async keyword without using await for all callers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186009/how-can-i-update-my-api-to-use-the-async-keyword-without-using-await-for-all-cal)

Comment: What exactly do you get? BTW you don't need to call line.Wait, Calling line.Result is a blocking call if the result is not available

Comment: I changed my method taking your comments into consideration. The app just hangs, I don't see anything in my output or locals window in VS 2012.

Comment: Are you running this from an UI thread?

Comment: Yes. I have a StreamSocket wrapper class which is called from the UI.

Comment: Is this client code reading from a network socket?

Comment: Yes. I am using StreamSocket and DataReader.

Comment: Did you make sure before attempting to read from the socket that there is any data available? Because if you attempt to read from a network socket and there is no data available, the call will simply hang waiting for the server to write something to this socket.

Comment: Yes. This is how I check: uint header = await stream.LoadAsync(8192); if (header == 0) throw new Exception("Client Disconnected!");

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but to me this looks like an issue with the client attempting to read something from the socket which is not available. I could be wrong of course.

Comment: Have a look a Stephen Cleary's article [Don't Block on Async Code](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.cz/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), it's most likely what's happening to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As some commented on the answer to your other question, if you use `Task.Result` in a GUI application, you may [cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I explain in detail on my blog).

In short:

- You start the asynchronous operation on the UI thread. Note that the task `line` represents the `ReadLineAsync` method, and will complete when that method completes.
- `ReadLineAsync` calls `await` on some operation that is incomplete. This causes `ReadLineAsync` to return an incomplete task (`line`).
- You block the UI thread waiting for `line` to complete.
- When the `await`ed operation completes, it schedules the remainder of `ReadLineAsync` to the UI thread.
- The UI thread cannot complete `ReadLineAsync` because it is synchronously blocked waiting for `ReadLineAsync` to complete. Deadlock.

See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186009/how-can-i-update-my-api-to-use-the-async-keyword-without-using-await-for-all-cal/14189020#14189020) for a way around this deadlock. In short:

- Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere.
- Change your error handling to account for `Result` wrapping its errors in `AggregateException`.

Answer (score -2):

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx
Shouldn't you be doing:

```
internal static string ReadLine(this DataReader stream)
{
   string line = await ReadLineAsync(stream);
   return line
}
```

That said, I haven't yet started with this Async business. But I've read documentations, etc.

Comment: You can't use `await` inside a non-`async` method

Comment: Yeah - i know now. I was a noob then :(